# post image and text field using ajax in php

Tags: ajax

here is my form i want to post text fields and image both in one ajax call

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="id_edit" disabled>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name_edit">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="job_edit">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email_edit">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="contact_edit">
 <input type="file" class="form-control" id="profile_edit">
</form>
```

here is my ajax script

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'PUT',
    url: 'team/' + id,
    data: {
    '_token': $("#token").val(),
    'id': $("#id_edit").val(),
    'name': $('#name_edit').val(),
    'job_title': $('#job_edit').val(),
    'email': $('#email_edit').val(),
    'contact': $('#contact_edit').val(),
    'profile': $('#profile_edit').val()
 }
```

Comment: Where is the image you are talking about?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I upload files asynchronously?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously)

Comment: Indented code to make it more readable